# A condition that balls have finite measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $\mu$ be a positive measure on $X$. I want to require that $(X,d)$ and $\mu$ have either of the following properties:

1. $\forall y \in X$, $\forall r \geq 0$, $\{x : d(x,y) = r\}$ has finite measure (according to $\mu$).
2. $\forall y \in X$, $\forall r \geq 0$, $\{x: d(x,y) \leq r\}$ has finite measure (according to $\mu$).

(That is, I am interested in the case where I impose #1 and in the case where I impose #2.)

My questions are:

1. Are the requirements equivalent? (*Answered below: no.*)
2. Has either requirement been made before, and if so, what is it called and where can I learn about it?
3. Is either condition equivalent to or implied by some nicer or well-known condition on measure spaces?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Do you have an example of $\mu$ so that $\mu\left(\left\{x : d(x,y) = r\right\}\right)\not=0$?

Comment: @xavierm02: I could think of a discrete space, like the lattice of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with integer coordinates, where $\mu(A) = |A|$.

Comment: The only "bad" case I could think of would be something like the completely discrete metric, $d(x,y) = 1$ for all $y \neq x$. It seems like many reasonable conditions could rule such things out, but I'm wondering what the most general could be....

Comment: Maybe assuming the measure is regular makes the conditions equivalent? I haven't checked this, but it's something to look into.

Comment: @Suugaku: Note that Michael Greinecker's counterexample is a $\sigma$-finite regular measure.

Comment: Oh, indeed... Duh.

Answer (score 3):

Take the plane with the usual metric, and take $\mu$ to be Hausdorff $s$-dimensional measure, where $1<s<2$.  The disks have Hausdorff dimension $2$, so their $\mu$-measure is $\infty$.  The circles have Hausdorff dimension $1$, so their $\mu$-measure is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Just take $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with Lebesgue measure and the metric given by $$d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}.$$ Then $\{x:d(x,y)=r\}$ has always finite measure, but $\{x:d(x,y)<1\}$ has infinite measure. So the conditions are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ (with $d(x,y) = |x-y|$) and $\mu$ be the counting measure (ie, $\mu(A) = |A|$, and $\mu(A) = +\infty$ when $|A|$ not finite). Then the spheres will have measure 2, but the balls will have infinite measure.